# Добавление книг в БД Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой  - добавление книги по главам в БД. Вот как выглядит модель

```
class Model(models.Model):
    book_text = models.FileField(uploads_to='media/book.fb2')
```

Добавить весь текст за один раз - без проблем, но как сделать вывод по главам ?

Сделать много полей для разных глав, не очень решение, а есть ли другое ?

Comment: Сделайте 3 модели) `Book`, `Сhapter`, `Text` и свяжите их друг с другом

Comment: С полями `ForeignKey` , дополняю ответ выше. Модель `Text` лишняя, текст в главе хранится

Comment: @ZaArs, питон будет обрабатывать файлы fd2 формата точно также, как и обычный txt?

Comment: безпонятия, но по идее, если отроешь в  редакторе файл, то это будет просто текст, вроде как. Скажу точно, что `fb2` обработается как и любой другой файл